# Prometheus - Alert when count increases steadily

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to create an alert for below cases.

A. Metric name is `docker_push_messages_api_failed_total` and of type `counter`.
Alert when, continuous or steady rise of counter during an hour.
Came up with below options and both are giving back results but unsure whether I'm handling this right ?

```
a) increase(docker_push_messages_api_failed_total[1h])
b) avg_over_time(docker_push_messages_api_failed_total[1h])
```

B. Metric name is `flight_api_calls_to_mq_total`, of type `counter` and the label used `status`
real time metric looks like this -

```
flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="",region="EMEA"} 40.0  or flight_api_calls_to_mq_total{status="arrived",region="US"} 10.0
```

Alert when `status` is `transit` for an hour.   Unsure what function can be used for this scenario, does `increase()` helps here ?

Comment: @markalex : Understood, sorry about that.

Comment: A. a) is might be what you want, but with addition of comparison. Try it this way: `increase(docker_push_messages_api_failed_total[1h]) > 2`. Adjust value as you need. Or alternatively you might use [`deriv()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#deriv), depending on the situation you need to monitor.

Comment: B. is really depends on what is you situation, and how your metric is acting: when it changes, how it changes and so on. It would be wise to edit it out of this question, and create separate question with all needed information.

Comment: @markalex :  thanks for the inputs, I'll post a new one for case 2. Appreciate your help.